# Reference request: Crystals and quasicrystals

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, symmetry, integer-lattices

I'm interested in the mathematics of crystals and quasicrystals--things like the enumeration of Bravais lattices and space groups, Bieberbach's results on higher dimensional lattices, and the cut and project construction for quasicrystals.  Could someone suggest a reference for this?

Also, from the [Wikipedia article on space groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_group), it looks like the enumeration of these groups is a complicated *ad hoc* procedure which tripped up pretty much everyone who attempted a solution.  If anyone could comment on systematic or algorithmic approaches to this problem, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What are quasi-crystals in this context ? is it with the Fourier transform ?

Comment: @user1952009 See [this Wikipedia page for an explanation of quasicrystals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasicrystal).

Comment: It doesn't define it. A definition I know is if $\{a_k\},\{b_m\}$ are sets of points of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and for some non-zero $c_k,d_m$ the Fourier transform of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k\delta(x-a_k)$ is  $\sum_{m=1}^\infty d_m \delta(x- b_m)$ then $\{a_k\},\{b_m\} $ are quasi-crystals.

Comment: @user1952009 That's already a definition I've not seen before :)  Learning characterizations like that is why I am asking this question.  FWIW, the [Wikipedia article on aperiodic tilings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_tiling) has a bit more detail, but it still doesn't include your distributional definition.  Thanks for that idea.

Comment: I rather liked [Quasicrystals and Geometry](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/mathematical-physics/quasicrystals-and-geometry?format=PB&isbn=9780521575416), by Marjorie Senechal.

Answer (score 1):

The book *[On Quaternions and Octonions](https://books.google.com/books/about/On_Quaternions_and_Octonions.html?id=E_HCwwxMbfMC)* has a systematic enumeration of the 3 and 4 dimensional groups in Chapters 3 and 4.